# Is there a way to write a "foreign" image so a Fujifilm X camera will display it?

Tags: metadata, memory-card, fujifilm

I have a paranoia about accidentally formatting SD cards which contain photos I haven't uploaded yet. I try to be careful about it, but since I'm sometimes juggling two or three cards, I still get nervous.

I have an import script which sucks in photos and verifies correct transfer, but I don't have a good way to then mark the SD card as "safe to delete". Obviously, there are a few things I could do in the physical world (lock and unlock the card, or put it in a special location, etc.), but I'm sometimes absent-minded or distracted and I'd rather the computer take care of it.

Of course, I could also format the card itself as part of the script, but... it seems like that's actually primarily introducing another possible disaster, if my error handling has bugs, for example. Additionally, I like to wait until later to format the card, because my upload process just saves locally, while a day later the overnight backup will have copied them offsite.

One idea I had was to write a JPEG (or other image) to the card with a nice green background and the text "safe to format!" — then, when I see that with the card in the camera, I'd know to trigger the in-camera format options.

But, I can't seem to get the camera to actually display any image I construct. Is there particular metadata, location, or other trick that will get the camera to recognize this file?

Comment: What's the difference between having your script delete the files vs. letting it put a picture on the card so that you format the card on camera? How does the latter prevent the possible disasters that stop you from doing the former?

Comment: @null With the latter, there's no inherently-destructive automated behavior. Let's say I make an error in changing the earlier part of the script and the files are instantly /dev/nulled instead of saved, and the script continues on merrily to the format before I have a chance to intervene. Oops.

Comment: I guess you could try the script during its development for such errors? What if you delete the files on camera while you are *absent-minded or distracted* without checking the results of the script? Oops?! Maybe buying a few more SD cards and never deleting any files during a session/trip is the simpler solution.

Comment: Of course I will, but... by definition, bugs that make it through are usually ones you didn't test for. Whereas "don't format the card unless it has the 'safe' marker" seems like a pretty easy habit to establish.

Comment: Which camera is it? Most Fuji show images taken from another camera with a small 'gift' icon. Try downloading a non-Fuji image onto the card to see if it works.

Comment: It is the X-T10. I did create an image in GIMP, and it wasn't displayed.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about the definition of a photography question here. We often dismiss Photoshop questions. I guess this is more about photography workflow, but still seems quite image-processing-oriented rather than a "real" photography question. (Albeit, I do think it's a good question!)

Comment: @osullic, Yes; I almost tagged it "workflow", and tried to put it in the context of doing photography. If I'd asked the same question about doing this in order to use my camera as a makeshift presentation tool, I'd vote for closing it as off topic. :) I try to apply the same logic to Photoshop questions as well.

Comment: @mattdm About ~5 years ago, I was able to inject computer-generated images onto an SD card and make the camera show it. My trick was to create baseline 4:2:2 Huffman JPEG images where the width and height are multiples of 8. (Avoid progressive, 4:4:4, and arithmetic coding.) Let me know if this works for you or you need additional info. I hope this can be turned into a full answer.

Comment: While the application of the OP may be OT, the idea of having images originating from somewhere else display on the camera is IMO perfectly valid (e.g. for displaying (portfolio) slideshows on a TV/projector without the need for another device, portfolio always with the photographer or having a visiting card on display if the camera is lost). Furthermore, it is a question about workflow and camera technology, and there is no specialized stackexchange for either. Please, do not close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of just dumping irrelevant code, here's a Perl program that I used for a similar purpose - transferring images to a printer with a card reader (before I was able to locate the printer near enough to use its USB connection).  It has some built-in assumptions (that card filesystems are user-mountable under `/media/card/<card-type>`) but you should be able to discard the `mount`/`umount` part if it's not relevant to you.  (If I were writing it again from scratch, I'd probably use `pmount` instead.)

There's also an attempt to give non-JPEG images a suitable thumbnail file as prescribed by DCIM; I can confirm that this works on my Canon DSLR, but I can't remember whether I tested it on a Fuji.  If I did, it would be on a F30 or F60 compact.

FWIW, my card-reading script (not shown) deletes each image from the card filesystem when it has been correctly written to my archive directory (and marked readonly).  I have a `--keep` option to override that, which is useful when testing changes to the script.  I never re-format the cards.

#### The code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

# Usage: write-image.pl file... dest
# dest is a dcf root directory - i.e. it contains a dcim subdir.

my $verbose = '';
my $rotate = '';
my $clear = '';

GetOptions ("clear!" => \$clear,
            "rotate!" => \$rotate,
            "verbose!" => \$verbose);

my $basedir = "/media/card";
if (@ARGV < 2) {
    die "not enough arguments\n";
}

my $dest = pop;
$dest = "$basedir/$dest" unless $dest =~ /^\//;

my $mounted = -d "$dest/dcim";
unless ($mounted) {
    print "mount $dest\n" if $verbose;
    system("mount", "$dest") == 0 or die;
}

if ($clear && -d "$dest/dcim") {
    clear(<$dest/dcim/*>);
}

# scan image directories
my $dirno = 99;
my $destdir;
foreach (<$dest/dcim/*>) {
    $dirno = $1 if /\/([1-9][0-9][0-9])/;;
    $destdir = $_ if /\/([1-9][0-9][0-9])linux$/;
}

unless ($destdir) {
    die if ++$dirno > 999;
    $destdir = "$dest/dcim/${dirno}linux";
    print "Adding new directory $destdir\n" if $verbose;
    -d "$dest/dcim" or mkdir"$dest/dcim" or die;
    mkdir $destdir or die;
}

# scan files
my $fileno = 0;
foreach (<$destdir/????[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*>) {
    /\/....([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\..*/;
    $fileno = $1 if $1 > $fileno;
}

sub clear(@) {
    my $f;
    foreach $f (@_) {
         if (-d $f) {
             &clear(<$f/*>);
             #print STDERR "rmdir  $f\n";
             rmdir $f;
         } else {
             #print STDERR "unlink $f\n";
             unlink $f;
         }
    }
}

#do it
foreach (@ARGV) {
    if (++$fileno > 9999) {
        die if ++$dirno > 999;
        $fileno = 1;
        $destdir = "$dest/dcim/${dirno}linux";
        mkdir $destdir or die;
    }
    my $destfile = sprintf "$destdir/img_%04d", $fileno;
    my $suffix = "";
    if (/\.[^.]+\Z/) {
        $suffix = $&;
    }
    #print "$_ -> $destfile$suffix\n" if $verbose;
    print "$_: " if $verbose;   # no newline!
    if ("$suffix" eq ".jpg") {
        if ($rotate) {
            system("( jpegtran -rot 90 -perfect $_ || djpeg $_ | pnmflip -cw | cjpeg -quality 95 -dct float -sample 1x1 ) > $destfile.jpg && exiftran -g -i $destfile.jpg") == 0 || die;
        } else {
            system("exiftran", "-g", "-o", "$destfile.jpg", "$_") == 0 || die;
            print sprintf(" -> img_%04d$suffix\n", $fileno) if $verbose;
        }
    } else {
        system("/bin/cp $_ $destfile$suffix") == 0 || die "$!\n";
        system("anytopnm $_ 2>&- | pnmscale -xysize 160 120 | pnmpad -width 160 -height 120 | pnmtojpeg >$destfile.thm") ==0 || die "$!\n";
        print "\n" if $verbose;
    }
}

unless ($mounted) {
    print "umount $dest\n" if $verbose;
    system("umount", "$dest") == 0 or die;
}
```

Again, I apologise for the length.  But it should now be clear where to write the image in the card's filesystem: in particular, according to the [DCIM](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-009-2010_E.pdf) standard, it must be in `DCIM/nnnAAAAA/AAAAnnnn.ext`, where `n` is numeric, `A` is any character¹, and `ext` is `JPG` or `THM` depending on whether it's the object itself or a separate thumbnail.  If the name doesn't fit this pattern, the camera will likely ignore it.

Note also the use of `exiftran -g` to add an EXIF thumbnail (of the correct size) to an image that doesn't have one.  That is likely important for your use, as cameras tend to rely on the thumbnail for image preview.  The one created by GIMP is probably the wrong size, and may cause your camera to ignore the image, display a placeholder or even report a read error.

---

¹ That is, any character within the quite restricted set allowed by DCIM: `123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`.

Comment: Ah — yeah, my created image had no thumbnail, and I didn't name it according to the DCIM specs. I'll try both things.

Comment: This worked. I had to create the thumbnail with `exiftran -g`, because for some reason the one created by GIMP causes a read error (wrong size, perhaps). Have a file with no thumbnail also causes a read error. (If the file is named according to the DCIM spec, that is; otherwise, it's just not processed.)

Comment: @matt, thanks for the extra information; I've updated.  I think you have identified why the `exiftran` line is in there (I'm a GIMPer too).  It's nice to know that my old, no-longer-used script was worth hanging on to!  :-)

Comment: Another fun fact: using `DCIM/999_AAAA/AAAA9999.JPG` causes the camera to display an error (I forget the exact phrasing, but something about hitting a numeric limit) and not respond to anything — you can't even format the card.

Comment: Sadly, this approach totally fails with my X-T2. Not sure why.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know what is required to recognize the "foreign" image, probably something in the Exif...  but for your goal, just create the image with your message, with appropriate background, and take a picture of it when showing on the home computer screen.  Then it is already in the camera.

Comment: LOL! Very elegant! :-)

Comment: Indeed, just write "Safe to format!" on a piece of paper with a marker and take a photograph of that. Copy this image back to each SD card after uploading the photos from that card.

Comment: If he is going to put the card in the camera and then take a picture of it to show that it's safe to delete the images, why not just delete the images at that time instead of taking the picture? Taking the picture doesn't seem to add any additional measure of safety.

Comment: The whole point is to script the operation so that it can be done without thinking

Comment: WayneF and osullic mean making his **import script** write that "proper" image to the card when the upload of all images is complete.

Comment: @Johnny: He will transfer this picture to his computer and make it a part of his script.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul He said he wants to delete the images using the camera format option, not from the script: _when I see that with the card in the camera, I'd know to trigger the in-camera format options._

Comment: Instead of taking a new "safe to delete" picture every time, just take one "safe to delete" picture, transfer it to/save it in the computer, and you now have an image that you can copy to the camera at the end of the script.